# PHP tree traversal perfomance: recursive function vs. loop with custom array as stack

Tags: php, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I have two functions in PHP that looks like the following, both trying to do something to each end-node of a tree.

```
function recurse(array $tree) {
    foreach($tree as $subtree) {
        if(!is_array($subtree)) {
            do_some_thing($subtree);
        } else {
           recurse($subtree);
        }
    }
}

function dfs(array $tree) {
    $stack = [$tree];
    while (!empty($stack)) {
        $subtree = array_pop($stack);
        if(!is_array($subtree)) {
            do_some_thing($subtree);
        } else {
            for ($i = count($subtree) - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
                $stack[] = $subtree[$i];
            }
        }
    }
}

// TESTING DATA:
// function do_some_thing($node) {
//     echo $node;
// }

// recurse([1,2,[3,4,[5],6],7]);
// 0.000156s
// 0.000163s
// 0.000157s
// 0.000168s
// 0.000143s

// dfs([1,2,[3,4,[5],6],7]);
// 0.000293s
// 0.000201s
// 0.001716s
// 0.000335s
// 0.000169s
```

I think the dfs() function should be better because system call-stack must be bigger than a user-defined stack but am not 100% sure because my test result on PHP-Sandbox seems to indicate the opposite. The recurse method seems to have very stable timing and is fast. The dfs method seems to have high-standard-deviation timing result and is slow on average. I would like to know what is the reason and is this always the case.

Also I don't know in either way, how big a difference there is, theoretically, for larger trees as I wasn't able to generate such a large dataset.

Comment: With limitations on recursion depth, recurse function can exhaust the limit on large trees but would work just fine for the second solution. To get the performance difference, you will need to test on large inputs. Since foreach creates a copy, it should slow down as the input size increases.

Comment: I have tried to increase the size to around 40 nodes with more depth `([1,2,[3,4,[5],6],7, 8, 9, [10, 11, [12, 13, 14, [15, 16, 17, 18], 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, [24,25,26,27,28,29,30,[31,32,33,34,35,[36,37],38,39,40]]]]]);` but still getting the same timing tendency. There must be some reason.

Comment: Caught up with something else. Meanwhile can you check with like 100 or 1000 nodes(auto-generate it of course)?  Can you also change `$stack[]` to `array_push` call and check again?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't really know how to generate a testing tree. I was entering the test data manually.

Comment: Changing $stack[] to array_push does seem to make a difference. There are still some occasional large timing result but not as often and not as big, and that happens to recurse as well.